# ASP .NET Core - sign in as other user / impersonate user and way back

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

As a member of an administrative role want to impersonate another user in my ASP .NET Core web application.

Basically I want to do this:

[image: login as another user]

I know that I can login as another user with:

```
await _signInManager.SignInAsync(appuser, false);
```

For a button **"Go back to my own account"** - how can I *know* that I'm currently impersonating another user and provide a "way back" to my own account.

Are there any built-in methods for this scenario?

[image: go back to my account]

Screenshots taken from [ASP.NET Zero](https://aspnetzero.com/)

Comment: Not sure if this will work in Core, but that's how I've done it in Identity v2: http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/06/user-impersonation-with-asp-net-identity-2/ I'm sure Core principles have not changed massively

Comment: @trailmax Thank you. This was the right direction (see my answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it with the following code.

In AccountController:

```
    [Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ImpersonateUser(string id)
    {
        var appUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        var userPrincipal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(appUser);
        userPrincipal.Identities.First().AddClaim(new Claim("OriginalUserId", User.FindFirst(x=>x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value));

        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync(); //sign out the current user

        //https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/IdentityCookieOptions.cs
        await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("Identity.Application", userPrincipal); //impersonate the new user

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> StopImpersonation()
    {
        var originalUserId = User.Claims.First(x => x.Type == "OriginalUserId").Value;
        var appUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(originalUserId);
        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(appUser, false);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Basically this adds the claim `OriginalUserId` to the impersonated user. By checking if this claim exists I know I'm currently impersonating and can provide a way back to the original account using the code in `StopImpersonation`.

The authentication scheme `Identity.Application` is the default.

Comment: Good solution! Glad my blog helped

Comment: Nice idea, though `HttpContext.Authentication` is [marked as obsolete](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=845470) since July 2017. So the line should also be replaced with `await _signInManager.SignInAsync(userPrincipal, false);`

Comment: @axuno, did you mean await _signInManager.SignInAsync(appUser, false); ?

Comment: @Campinho: yes, indeed